# Rewriting mulitple URLS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, rewriting

I am trying to rewrite different URLs. The first three lines work, but lower ones do not. I get a 500 Internal Server Error. A snippet of my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^word/(.*)$ word.php?word=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/en/word/(.*)$ /en/word.php?word=$1 [QSA]
```

It would be very nice if someone could help me, as I can't find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Greetings,
Andreas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please keep your .htaccess file inside your root folder.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^word/(.*)$ word.php?word=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^en/word/(.*)$ en/word.php?word=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```